# HTML input gets cleared on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that writes the value of an `<input>` field to a cookie, then refreshes the page. The page must be refreshed so that the server side can re-render the page based on the values from the cookie.

However I do not want the user to lose the value they type in the `<input>` field, unless they erase it.

How can I achieve this with javascript?

Comment: Are you saying the input box should have the same value after the refresh as it did before the refresh?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is refreshing the page manually, check out window.onbeforeunload.

If the user is posting the form, then spit out the value server side or use JavaScript to get the cookie value.

Comment: i am confused, do you put that in the input box tag?

Answer (score 0):

Don't refresh. Redirect the user back to the same url, but with an extra querystring parameter. Pick this up in JS and populate the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set the value of the text input after the refresh, use this Javascript:

```
var inputval = getCookie('nameofcookie');

if(inputval != NULL && inputval != "") {

     document.getElementById('idofinput').value = inputval;

}
```

Replace "nameofcookie" with the name of the cookie that the input value is stored in, and replace "idofinput" with the ID of the text input field.

Comment: when and where would that code snippet be executed, inside the function that refreshes the page or outside?

Comment: Outside the function, when the page is loaded.